# Does regular expression allow you to replace the ending and beginning of a word?

Tags: regex, replace, gruntfile

I'm having one heck of a time figuring out regular expression in the context of the grunt-string-replace plugin.

I'm basically trying to take something like this:

```
!random-cssmixin{}
```

And turn it into this:

```
.random-cssmixin;
```

Is it possible to do this or does regular expression simply allow to you manipulate the text between?

My Gruntfile.js:

```
'string-replace': {
          dist: {
              expand: true,
              flatten: true,
              src: devRoot + ['/css/*.less'],
              dest: sqsRootCss,
          options: {
              replacements: [{
                   pattern: /\$/g,
                   replacement: "@"
              }, {
                  pattern: "No clue",
                  replacement: "No idea"

              }]
            }
          },
      },
```

Comment: what is your sample input and expected output?

Comment: I put the example at the top of the question. I'm writing LESS CSS using the format !random-class{} and the expected output should be .random-class;

Comment: The reason I'm going through this is because I'm using some grunt plugins, one of which is autoprefixing. I'm writing CSS in LESS syntax, but I do NOT want the CSS compiled because my website CMS SaaS platform does this for me. So my output needs to be in uncompiled LESS. The problem is the Autoprefix doesn't understands LESS, so it breaks. To get around this I'm creating my own syntax using supported characters like the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
!([\w-]+)\{\}
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/gV4cU9/2)**

And then use the replacement string:

```
.\1;
```

Check the `substitution section` to see your expected output

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it's doing something, but it's basically wiping out the entire CSS file replacing nearly everything. http://imgur.com/CI4uXpe

Comment: Any way to specifically state it as "starting with ! and ending with {}"

Comment: @jasonbarone fixed, use the regex `!([\w-]+)\{\}`

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I modified the replacement for grunt-string-replace.         pattern: /!([\w-]+)\{\}/g, replacement: '.$1;'